# I moved a discussion to chat, but I'm not logged in there

Tags: support, chat, login

I just had a lengthy discussion moved to chat. On the chat page, I am not logged in. When I click the link "you need to be logged in", I get to the Stack Exchange page ("Logging you in to the Stack Exchange chat…"), where nothing happens. The login test page shows that everything is OK. However, I can't chat. What is wrong?

Comment: Chat login is tricky. There should be a "or login via stack exchange" (or something similar) link somewhere on the page. Try clicking that and logging in.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't think I have any of the types of account there. I thought I had a Google account, but I ended up creating a new blank account. I will try to delete that account and attempt to login to the chat room again.